# Add Anonymous Users into an Engagement Plan

Tags: engagement-plans

Is there a way to automatically add visitors to a specific site definition to a specific engagement plan OOTB?

Is there a way this could be implemented programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a user to an engagement plan (EP) with code is very simple. You just need to new up an AutomationStateManager and enroll the user in the EP. Just supply the ID of the EP.

```
var a = AutomationStateManager.Create(Tracker.Current.Contact);
a.EnrollInEngagementPlan([ID of the EngagementPlan], IDs.EngagementPlans.State.BeginingState);
```

Comment: What namespace is `AutomationStateManager` in?  And what version of Sitecore is this in relation to?

Comment: @DylanYoung Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data in assembly Sitecore.Analytics.Automation. Its been around since at least 8.1 update 0. Could be older.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in couple of ways:

**1. Using the WFFM Module save action.**

You can find more info on the official documentation [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/engagement_plans/creating_engagement_plans/use_a_web_form_to_enroll_a_visitor_in_an_engagement_plan)

**2. Using the campaign trigger**

This is a way of achieving what you need without additional modules, but a bit hacky.

1. Create a campaign and associate it with the desired plan. [documentation link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/engagement_plans/creating_engagement_plans/associate_a_campaign_activity_with_an_engagement_plan)
2. Add the script to your page: `<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { $.get('/?sc_camp=[campaignid]'); });</script>`. Alternatively, you can add this query string element `?sc_camp=[campaignid]` to the required page.